# Twitter API destroying stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

Here is my code:

```
class Stream {
    constructor(client) {
        this.client = client
        this._stream = {};
    }
    async start() {
            const stream = this.client.tw.stream("statuses/filter", {
                follow: "user IDs"
            })
            this._stream = stream;

            stream.on("tweet", tweet => {
             //code
            })

    }
    async destroy() {
        //console.log(this._stream)
        return this._stream.destroy();
    }
}

module.exports = Stream;
```

When I want to destroy my stream, I get `this._stream.destroy is not a function` error. Any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what twitter api module are you using?

Comment: ah sorry I forgot to mention that. I am using twit package.